# How many 5-letter words can be formed out of the letter of the 'EQUATION', if repetition of letters is not allowed?

Tags: combinatorics

> How many 5-letter words can be formed out of the letter of the
>   'EQUATION', if repetition of letters  is not allowed?

Well, we just want to permute a subset of size 5 out of the bigger set of 8, say points or letters. This can be done in $8 \times 7 \times 6 \times 5 \times 4 = 6720$

However, the answer in the book says $15120$. What is the flaw here? or the flaw is in the book answer sheet?

Comment: Permuting the letters does not allow you to repeat a letter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is it possible the question is asking about the word "EQUATIONS"? The solution in the book is $9!/4! =  \space_9\text{P}_5$, which would be the correct answer for a $9$-letter word with no repeating letters.

If the question is as you stated it here, then your answer is correct, being $8!/3! = \space_8 \text{P}_5$